# C# хранение и запуск файла программы внутри другой программы как ресурса

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources

Есть ли возможность интегрировать внешнюю программу (формат .exe) в мой проект как, к примеру, ресурс? Как потом запустить такую программу?

Хочу сделать обёртку для exiftool. Хочу чтобы моя программа передавала внутреннему exiftool информацию о фотографии и получала результат, который далее необходимо реструктуризировать силами самой программы.

Смысл в том, чтобы дополнительный файл не создавался, а загружался в память и выполнялся без физического дискретного существования

Comment: Добавить файл в ресурсы, при запуске программы сохранять его на диск, например во временную папку, и запускать как обычный процесс. А вы смотрели в NuGet пакетах, быть может там есть подходящая библиотека для работы с exif? Или на GitHub.

Comment: Простых методов запуска процесса без существования файла на диске нет, это архитектурное ограничение Windows, которое конечно можно обойти, но такое поведение может расцениваться операционной системой или антивирусным приложением как опасное, так как оно свойственно в основном компьютерным вирусам, которые в свою очередь любят этот трюк и используют его для обхода проактивной защиты антивируса.